# excel if cell contains number and certain character then

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need an excel formula that looks in column A and if the cell starts with a number and also has "-" in the cell and then ends with a number column B equals that cell.

Here's an example column A has random text and i want column B to only show the cells that start with a number and end with a number and also have the character "-" in the cell somewhere.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend applying a conditional that requires two things:

1) Numbers before and after a "-" character. That way if there is no "-" the formula throws an error and evaluates false.

2) Since your numbers can be more than a single character long you need to allow for search from the beginning of the cell to the "-" and from the end of the cell to a "-", thus determining the potential length of the number is required.

Try:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-1))),ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2))))),A2,"")
```

I entered this starting in B2 and filled down. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom Excel formulas using VB and regex. The regex you need to match that pattern is [0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] (This will match anything from 0-0 up to 99-99).

If you follow the instructions here: [How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)

It will teach you everything you need to know :)